# How to create a simple undirected network in Gephi

Tags: python, social-networking, gephi

I am new to Gephi and want to create simple but specific network networks in Gephi.

How would I create an input file or draw graphs? Is there an api (python) I could use to do this?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: See the csv import option: https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/csv-format/. You should be able to use Python to wrangle your data into an appropriate format using this option!

Answer (score 2):

Gephi is more focused on Java (but there is also an API for Python). The input file can have multiple formats, so I suggest you to select one from [this list](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/) and go ahead.

As you are new to Gephi, and you want to use it from Python, maybe you should **take a look to other options** like [Networkx](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/gallery.html), which is a pure Python module.

Comment: Hi PX, thanks, I am having problems getting to the Gephi sites including the one you listed. I downloaded NetworkX to Mint-15 and will look at it. I was hoping for an application I could graphically lay down nodes, connect them and it would run on Mint/Ubuntu. Any further thoughts? One of my networks is only 10 nodes.

Comment: @ChrisRigano I didn't use NetworkX but it seems to be easy to use it for your simple network.